# Create TableView in the same View

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know esque I can do when I click Finish"-(IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id) sender " on the keyboard, I view a tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view controller which contains the table view and populate it when the user finishes editing and then show the view controller's view as subview if you want it on the same view controller or you can also push it in the navigation stack if you have one.

Comment: there is not something like iPad when I click the bottom left behind and found the tableView. like the trick when there 's a WiFi wireless iPhone displays a tableView or there are the names of WiFi